# SQL Queries in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I am very new to ASP.NET. I have Visual Studio Express 2013 and MSSql Server that contains a bunch of databases. I watching a few tutorials about MVC/Entity framework to retrieve data from a table and display it. However, it is using Linq to SQL which I am not familiar with. All I need is to write a sql query to combine information in two tables and display it in the view. I could not find this simple tutorial on the internet. Can anyone give me a hint please?

Comment: Why are you asking about LINQ to SQL. You may be confused. Don't use it. Use Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0):

To run a simple query you need to create a connection to the database like following:

```
var connection = new SqlConnection("your connecting string");
```

Once you have that you can connect to database and query using something called SqlCommand like following:

```
using (connection)
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
          "SELECT CategoryID, CategoryName FROM Categories;",
          connection);
        connection.Open();

       //fetches the data by executing the command
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                //You can process data here , read it from reader and process it
                // the index 0 and 1 indicate your query columns
                var somedata = reader.GetInt32(0) + reader.GetString(1));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //no data returned from query
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
```